# MySQL ROUND does not restrict the number of decimal places

Tags: mysql, rounding

I have a field in my table that is of type decimal(14,9) (not unsigned).
The table can be created and populated thus:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    num DECIMAL(14,9),
    owner CHAR(5)
);
INSERT INTO test(num, owner) VALUES(1.5, 'mine');
INSERT INTO test(num, owner) VALUES(2.5, 'yours');
INSERT INTO test(num, owner) VALUES(0, 'mine');
INSERT INTO test(num, owner) VALUES(1.5, 'mine');
```

My Query:
`SELECT owner, ROUND(num, IF(num = 0, 0, 5)) num FROM test;`

I intended for the 0 values to come back as 0 (with no decimal places shown), but for some reason, it keeps returning values of 0.0000000000

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question. ROUND() only rounds the number, leaving it the same kind of decimal with the same precision and decimal places, and FORMAT() would cut it off the way I want.  So, the query should have been `SELECT owner, FORMAT(num, IF(num = 0, 0, 5)) num FROM test;`